# R combine rows of matrix if any element matches element of any other row

Tags: r

I would like to combine rows from a matrix into a list element, if at least one of the values in the row equals one of the values in the other row. And do this row-combining iteratively (all rows with all other rows). I'm sorry for the bad explanation. An example to clarify:

```
mymatrix <- matrix(data = c(2, 3, 4, 22, 7, 11, 8, 13, 17, 19, 20,
                            4, 36, 8, 2, 29, 35, 40, 14, 21, 20, 21),
                   nrow = 11, ncol = 2)
row.names(mymatrix) <- c(3, 6, 7, 10, 12, 17, 18, 19, 24, 26, 28)
```

The result of some function should be:

```
myresult <- list(c(2, 4, 4, 8, 22, 2, 8, 40),
                 c(3, 36),
                 c(7, 29),
                 c(11, 35),
                 c(13, 14),
                 c(17, 21, 20, 21, 19, 20))
```

So rows 1,3,4,7 of the original matrix are combined (to be clear, the ones with rownames 3,7,10,18), as are the bottom 3 rows.

It's also fine if the solution will have removed the duplicates (and/or sorted the integers) within each list element, as I'll do that anyway otherwise.

In that case it would look like this:

```
myresult <- list(c(2, 4, 8, 22, 40),
                 c(3, 36),
                 c(7, 29),
                 c(11, 35),
                 c(13, 14),
                 c(17, 19, 20, 21))
```

Maybe I can accomplish this by doing a merge of the matrix with itself, but I'm at a loss at how to do this correctly. Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a graph cluster problem; You can use `igraph` package for this:

```
library(igraph)

# change the vertice name type to character
mode(mymatrix) <- 'character'

# create the graph
g <- graph_from_edgelist(mymatrix)

# find out the cluster
members <- clusters(g)$membership

# split nodes by membership
split(names(members), members)
#$`1`
#[1] "2"  "4"  "8"  "22" "40"

#$`2`
#[1] "3"  "36"

#$`3`
#[1] "7"  "29"

#$`4`
#[1] "11" "35"

#$`5`
#[1] "13" "14"

#$`6`
#[1] "17" "21" "19" "20"
```